# SharePoint 2013 People:Assistant returns empty when created as Managed Property

Tags: c#, sharepoint, display-templates

If I create a Managed Property that points to the `People:Assistant` property it always returns an empty string if set to text or undefined if set to binary.

The Assistant property is of type Person and I want to use the properties to create a link to the Assistant profile.

What I have done is:
Fill out the Assistant field in a user Profile

Create a new Managed Property called assistant

1. Type: Text
2. Retrievable: true
3. Mapping: `People:Assistant`

In the display template add Assistant to the managed properties
Save everything and for good measure do a crawl.

Check that Assistant is set to another Person on the profile

Debug the display template and check `ctx.CurrentItem.Assistant`.
It returns "".

If I set the Managed Property type to binary then it returns *undefined*

I have also tried `ctx.CurrentItem.Assistant[0]` or `ctx.CurrentItem.Assistant["PreferredName"]`

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I would either return the Person object as a managed property or get a reference to it so that I can create a new Person object and access the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out what I was missing. When setting up the managed property, set it to text and click the *Advanced Searchable Settings* and select *PeopleIdx*

Do a full crawl and the managed property will return `<domain>\<username>` which can be used to create a link to the user.

All I have to do now is work out how to return the users display name from the domain address :-)